# Losing Data while uploding CSV to Bucket

Tags: function, csv, google-cloud-platform, bucket

To put it in context, I have a bucket where I storage CSV files and a function that works to put that Data into a Database when you load new CSV into the bucket.
I try to upload 100 CSV at the same time, in all, 581.100 records (70 MB)
All of those files appears in my bucket and a new table is created.
But when I do a “select count” I only found 267306 records (46 % of the total)
I try to do it again, different bucket, function, and table, I try to upload another 100 files, 4.779.100 records this time (312 MB)
When I check the table in big query I realize that only 2.293.920 records exist (47,9%) of the one that supposedly exist.
So my question is, is there a way in which I can upload all the CSV that I want without losing data? Or does GCP have some restriction for that task?
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Is the import done by your Cloud Functions? Or do you use the load feature un BigQuery?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your logs?
Have you validated if some of your data has been trimmed and/or is there any difference between your original files and the ones loaded into the database?
What method are you using to load your data into the database?
Have you tried using fewer files/smaller data?

Comment: Hello and good Afternoon. 
Here are the answers to your question, and thank you for reading my post.
• Is the import done by your Cloud Functions? Or do you use the load feature un BigQuery?
The import is done by my Cloud Fuctions, the data is in my bucket. 
• Do you have any errors in your logs? 
I have done this at least three times, I don’t see any error, maybe some kind of limit of information?

Comment: • Have you validated if some of your data has been trimmed and/or is there any difference between your original files and the ones loaded into the database? 
After the upload I went to bigquery and with a simple select I saw that the information that exists in my table are the same that exist in my bucket. (Referring just to the info that was actually able to exist in my table of course)

Comment: • What method are you using to load your data into the database? Have you tried using fewer files/smaller data?
The files are in a CVS format when I upload then into the bucket, in the bucket there`s an option that allows me to do so, if I upload the files in groups and not all the same time all the data is shown in my table, that`s why I think there’s could be some kind of restriction that I’m not aware of.

Comment: UPDATE: theres and error control code that i used, and I have 2 messages:"google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table" and "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
"

Comment: @NelsonRomero was my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73792897/13171940) helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in your last comment:

> google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table

This error shows that you have reached *the limit for maximum rate of table metadata update operations per table for Standard tables*, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas#ts-maximum-update-table-metadata-limit). You can review the limits that may apply [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables). Note that *this quota cannot be increased*.

In the **diagnosis** section, it says:

> Metadata table updates can originate from *API calls* that modify a table's metadata or from *jobs* that modify a table's content.

As a **resolution**, you can do the following:

> - Reduce the update rate for the table metadata.
> - Add a delay between jobs or table operations to make sure that the update rate is within the limit.
> - For data inserts or modification, consider using DML operations. DML operations are not affected by the  **Maximum rate of table metadata update operations per table**  rate limit.
>   DML operations have other  [limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#data-manipulation-language-statements)  and quotas. For more information, see  [Using data manipulation language (DML)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language).
> - If you frequently load data from multiple small files stored in Cloud Storage that uses a job per file, then combine multiple load jobs into a single job. You can load from multiple Cloud Storage URIs with a comma-separated list (for example,  `gs://my_path/file_1,gs://my_path/file_2`), or by using wildcards (for example,  `gs://my_path/*`).
>   For more information, see  [Batch loading data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data#permissions-load-data-from-cloud-storage).
> - If you use single-row queries (that is,  `INSERT`  statements) to write data to a table, consider batching multiple queries into one to reduce the number of jobs. BigQuery doesn't perform well when used as a relational database, so single-row  `INSERT`  statements executed at a high speed is  *not*  a recommended best practice.
> - If you intend to insert data at a high rate, consider using  [BigQuery Storage Write API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api). It is a recommended solution for high-performance data ingestion. The BigQuery Storage Write API has robust features, including exactly-once delivery semantics. To learn about limits and quotas, see  [Storage Write API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#write-api-limits)  and to see costs of using this API, see  [BigQuery data ingestion pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data_ingestion_pricing).

Comment: Hello to Everyone. 
thank you Rogelio for the insight, that could be a solucion that i could use the next time i face a problem like that